# Use paramiko with AWS Glue

Tags: python, aws-glue, paramiko

I am trying to connect from SFTP location using paramiko in python. Below is code for that -

```
try:
    ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(
        paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh_client.connect(hostname=ftp_host, username=ftp_username, password=ftp_password, port=ftp_port)
except Exception as error:
    print("Error occurred while connecting to ftp server: ", error)
    exit(1)
print("Established connection to file server successfully")
```

hostName, username, password is valid & connecting from local computer. Same script is working from local computer to fetch files from remote machine.

But, when I am trying to run SFTP on glue job, previously it through error -
NoModuleFound -- paramiko

Later when I searched & added whl files of paramiko it's giving error.

```
    ImportError: cannot import name 'asn1' from 'cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust' (unknown 
     location)
```

Comment: Include the part of your code that has `asn1`

Comment: paramiko is using internally to asn1.

Answer (score 1):

Using Glue 4.0, I was able to add the `--additional-python-modules` job parameter with value 'paramiko' to get this to work. I had previously tried the .whl file for paramiko and ran into the same error.

[image]